# Visiting Moscow on Stopover

Tags: visas, russia, stopovers, moscow, svo

Traveling to Moscow Aeroflot 21 hour layover, 4:30 p.m. leaving 2:20 next day.  Sight seeing, staying over at hotel.  Leaving from same airport.  Do we need travel Visa?

Comment: What's your citizenship?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are leaving the airport and do not only stay in airside transit, you will need a visa even though you're staying less than 24h - unless you're from one of the countries whose citizens are allowed visa free travel, see [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Russia#Visa-free_Entry) for a list of countries.

If you were staying airside in international transit and you're staying for less than 24h, you would not need a visa according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Russia#Direct_airside_transit):

> Direct airside transit
>
> Passengers travelling through international airports do not need a visa for a transit of less than 24 hours, provided a confirmed onward ticket is held and the traveller remains in the international transit area (without clearing passport control).
>
> Only five Russian airports have an international transit area:
>
> - Moscow's Sheremetyevo International Airport (SVO) - terminals D, E and F
> - Moscow's Domodedovo International Airport (DME)
> - Moscow's Vnukovo International Airport (VKO) - terminal A
> - Saint Petersburg's Pulkovo Airport (LED) - new terminal 1
> - Yekaterinburg's Koltsovo International Airport (SVX) - international terminal.

In addition to that, the [website of Novosibirsk Tolmachevo (OVB)](http://eng.tolmachevo.ru/passengers/information/transfer/index.php?sphrase_id=62537) states:

> Transit of transfer passengers from an international flight to an international flight (IAL-IAL) occurs with the passage of all departure procedures for boarding a connecting IAL flight at the airport of IAL (Terminal B).
>
> No Russian visa is required for a transit of transfer passengers from an IAL to an IAL of the connecting time of a flight is less than 4 hours and a passenger does not leave the airport. Arriving passengers are accommodated in the transfer hall in the sterile area on the second floor of the airport of an IAL (Terminal B).
>
> For transit of transfer passengers from an IAL flight to an IAL flight, in case if the connecting time exceeds 4 hours, the arrived transfer passengers shall go into the arrival hall on the first floor of the airport of an IAL (Terminal B) for passage of border control, baggage handling and customs control thereafter.

Comment: I wonder where they got this information about only five airports. I strongly suspect that Novosibirsk Tolmachevo (OVB) also has a transit area, and possibly some others, too.

Comment: that in itself doesn't mean anything. The map may be simply lacking a brown line for transfers that exists. Obviously, transit passengers are a tiny minority in OVB, so why bother putting their brown line on the map? Actually, I vaguely remember that I read an (atrocious) report from someone who flew Bangkok to Yerevan through Novosibirsk. Won't bet for that though. Perhaps, tomorrow I will phone the airport and ask them if airside TWOV is possible just to be sure.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy see my update to the answer and the included link.